# Decimal calculation different on my local machine vs Heroku server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I have a Django project that I deployed to Heroku. I noticed that the calculations are not working when I used smaller numbers for some reason. Everything works fine on my local Windows machine.

For example this calculation `newBalance = Decimal(str(userObj.user_coins)) - Decimal(str(betValue))`  when the calculation would be 2000 - 12 I get an answer of 2.0E+3 instead of 1988. If the calculation would be 2000 - 120 I get an answer of 1900 or 1.9E+3 instead of 1880. On my local machine this was working correctly.

I don't understand what might be going wrong here.

```
//Template script

$('.bet-submit').click(function() {
    const betValue = document.getElementById('bet-value').value
        
    betSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'id': id,
        'betValue': betValue
    }))
})

betSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    update_coins()

    for(const key in data.bets){
        document.querySelector('#bets').innerHTML += '<span>' +data.bets[key].bet_value +'$</span>'
    }
}

function update_coins() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
                url: "/api/coins/",
                data: {},
                success: function(data) {
                    document.querySelector('#user_coins').innerHTML = data.coins
                }
            })
        };
```

```
//consumers.py

async def receive(self, text_data):
    id= data['id']
    betValue = data['betValue']

    await save_bet(id, betValue)
    bets = await get_bets(round)

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'send_bet',
            'bets': bets
        }
    )



@database_sync_to_async
def save_bet(id, betValue):
    userObj = CustomUser.objects.filter(steam_id=steamid)[0]

    newBalance = userObj.user_coins - Decimal(betValue)
    print(newBalance) // 2.0E+3
   CustomUser.objects.filter(steam_id=steamid).update(user_coins=newBalance)

    ...


@database_sync_to_async
def get_bets(round):
    ...

    bets = {}
    for idx, bet in enumerate(betsObj):
        bets[str(idx)] = {}
        bets[str(idx)].update({
             ...,
            'bet_value': str(bet.bet_value),
        })

    return bets
```

Comment: I am saving the number to database and then displaying it on the front end again, the numbers are not being calculated correctly. @jfaccioni

Comment: What is the underlying type of `userObj.user_coints`? Is it [a `DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield), or something else? If it's [a `FloatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#floatfield), for example, all the work you're doing in Python with decimals and strings doesn't really matter: the value will lose precision when it's stored, and wrapping an irrational value from your database with `str()` doesn't make it rational.

Comment: The `userObj.user_coins` is a DecimalField. @Chris

Comment: And what is `betValue`? (If `user_coins` is a decimal you shouldn't need the `Decimal(str(...))` around it. I suggest you remove it since it isn't doing anything useful, and it suggests that `user_coins` might _not_ be a decimal value.)

Comment: In any case, this may not be a calculation error, it might just be a presentation error. it looks like you're printing values out in scientific notation. Where are you seeing these `2.0E+3` values? Assuming they're in a template somewhere, what is the template code?

Comment: The type of `betValue` is `<class 'str'>`.  I am saving the calculation result in a list as a string and sending it to the template. Also I am updating the `user_coins` value on database after the calculation like that `CustomUser.objects.filter(id=id).update(user_coins=newBalance)`. Since I did not see correct template number change nor the correct value change in database I decided to print out the result of the calculation in the backend and that's where I see the `2.0E+3` result. Hope that makes sense. @Chris

Comment: If it's already a string, why are you wrapping it in `str(...)`? Again, that is unnecessary and very confusing. "I am saving the value in a list as a string and sending it to the template"—please [edit] the relevant code into your question as a [mre]. Describing is a lot less clear than showing.

Comment: I have added the relevant code with the changes you suggest for the process. I've added the unnecessary str() and Decimal() as a precaution as I have understood that the only way to do an accurate calculation with decimal points is to have a decimal string calculation @Chris

Comment: Are you sure `userObj.user_coins` is 2000 and not 2020?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Though this is just an example. `userObj.user_coins` could be any other number and the calculation is still not accurate.@AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use `float` rather than `Decimal`.

```
newBalance = float(str(userObj.user_coins)) - float(str(betValue))
```

Comment: Do you have any insight on why using a float is better? Right now I am calculating all the "user_coins" numbers in Decimals in my code. @DavidLu